# How to access/get the value of a Variable inside a nested if statement to outside the main if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, file-io

I have this code sample which I was developing. Here I have declared two variables (initialPath, lastPath) outside the main if-else statement. Inside the main If statement there is a nested if-else statement. I have initialized the variable (initialPath) inside the nested if statement. I need that value to be used outside the nested if-else statement. I have attached my code snippet. If anyone can help to solve my problem, I'd be glad :)

```
    FileWriter writer;
    File initialPath=null;
    File lastPath=null;

    if (clicked == 1) {


        int sf = savefile.showSaveDialog(null);

        if (sf == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            initialPath=savefile.getSelectedFile(); // in here the Variable values is initialized/assigned

            try {

                if (savefile.getFileFilter().equals(filter2)) {

                    String path = savefile.getSelectedFile() + ".java";
                    File file = new File(path);
                    writer = new FileWriter(file, false);
                    System.out.println(savefile.getFileFilter());
                    writer.write(jTextPane1.getText());

                    writer.close();
                } else if (savefile.getFileFilter().equals(filter)) {

                    System.out.println("2");
                    String path = savefile.getSelectedFile() + ".txt";
                    File file = new File(path);
                    writer = new FileWriter(file, false);

                    writer.write(jTextPane1.getText());

                    writer.close();


                } else {
                    System.out.println("No format");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (sf == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {


            clicked = 0;

        }

    } else {


        try {

            lastPath=initialPath.getParentFile(); //but in here lastPath become NULL because initialPath is NULL... 

    //I need to get the value of initialPath to this ELSE statement

            if (savefile.getFileFilter().equals(filter2)) {

                String path = savefile.getSelectedFile() + ".java";
                File file = new File(path);
                writer = new FileWriter(file, false);
                System.out.println(savefile.getFileFilter());
                writer.write(jTextPane1.getText());

                writer.close();
            } else if (savefile.getFileFilter().equals(filter)) {

                String path = savefile.getSelectedFile() + ".txt";
                File file = new File(path);
                writer = new FileWriter(file, false);

                writer.write(jTextPane1.getText());

                writer.close();


            } else {
                System.out.println("No format");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: just declare it outside where you need it and then only do the initialization inside your if blocks. Edit: I just saw that it already is defined outside of the if-else statement and can be referenced outside it. So what exactly is your problem? Do you want to use the value in another method?

Comment: Why not use a function that returns a `File`?

Comment: No, I need to get the path location when I press the approve/save button in jfilechooser. So if I have declared the variable outside, I cannot get the file location.  @OHGODSPIDERS

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to move `initialPath=savefile.getSelectedFile();` outside of the `if` statement?

```
initialPath=savefile.getSelectedFile();
if (sf == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: No no sir, this is not What I want... in the Nested if statement, there is the jfilechooser, When it is appear and I press the approve button, I need to get the location of the file I saved. So If I have declared the variables outside as you said, I cannot get the file location path and assign it into the lastPath...

Comment: Really I need an option to get the last used path by the JFilechooser :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `initialPath` outside as you declared it outside. " I need that value to be used outside the nested if-else statement."

In a short example what you are doing:

```
File file;
if(true){
    file = /*you initialize here*/;
} else {
    /*if false file is never initialized but you want to use it here,
      its in scope but null of course.*/
}
```

Initialize file outside if you need it in both if and else blocks, if you can not initialize it outside you should not need that in the else block. A logical error is there.

Comment: No no sir, this is not What I want... in the Nested if statement, there is the jfilechooser, When it is appear and I press the approve button, I need to get the location of the file I saved. So If I have declared the variables outside as you said, I cannot get the file location path and assign it into the lastPath...

Comment: Really I need an option to get the last used path by the JFilechooser :)

Comment: @Code Bae I know this is not what you want. This is what you are currently doing, that's why I said there are logical problems here.